# How to do Real time Data Ingestion from AWS Oracle RDS to Dyanmo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

I have a problem statement where we need to trasnfer our On Premises Data to Dyanamo DB. For that we have used Oracle GG for realtime data pipeline from Online Premises Oracle DB to RDS DB. THis has been done. now we need to move the same relatime data continusouly to dynamoDb. Please do let us know what are the possible ways we can do that. Thanks

We are trying to find the we can do that. It's in analysis phase at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with [DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.HighLevelView.html):

*AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS) is a cloud service that makes it possible to migrate relational databases, data warehouses, NoSQL databases, and other types of data stores. You can use AWS DMS to migrate your data into the AWS Cloud or between combinations of cloud and on-premises setups.*

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_GettingStarted.Replication.html

Comment: Dear Lee, Thanks for your prompt response. but it seems my questions itself was not clear. Let me explain in detail here. We have Oracle DB in our on Premises and we are actually not migrating the whole database to AWS RDS but realtime copying a set of columns from multiple tables by using joins and move those data to AWS Oracle RDS by using Oracle GG. Now Let us suppose those data are in a Table xyz in Oracle RDS and data keeps on growing continuously realtime in table xyz. Now these data moved to DynamoDB on realtime. One application on AWS will consume these data from dynamoDB. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you replicate the data from RDS to DynamoDB in real time using DMS. I believe that's what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks Lee, but for Data Conversion from Oracle to Dynamodb also we need to do. So finally we thought to write few microservices in Spring batch and deployed in EKS, where data will be read from Oracle RDS and do the conversion and then send to dynamodb. here any data needs to update also which already in dynamodb we can do that as well.  is ths the right apporach ? Please suggest